# Best way for bidirectional referenced table rows for double-entry booking

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, google-drive, google-docs

I want to move to a Google Spreadsheets setup to handle my private booking.

Currently I have four tables:

- Overview
- Accounts
- Income
- Outcome

Except of "Overview" all share following columns:

- Date
- Type (e.g. Creditcard, Car, Job)
- Name (e.g. Amazon, GitHub)
- Description (e.g. Gift for Sandy)
- Book from (e.g. PayPal-Account)
- Increase
- Decrease
- Total

The problem I now have is that when I add a new row for outcome this will not be added to my account table so I need to add the outcome to the outcome table AND to the account table. I would now like to now if there is a function which could either include all table data dynamically from Income to Accounts or if there is a function which could add and remove automatically modified rows bidirectional.

Best,
Bodo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google spreadsheets does not fully support table relationships. [Google Fusion Tables](https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/2571232?hl=en) can get you close, but it's not what you're looking for.

If you use excel you can [create relationships between tables](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-a-relationship-between-two-tables-HA102837471.aspx) which is not possible with google spreadsheet. [Example](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/relationships-between-tables-in-a-data-model-HA102836654.aspx).

Comment: what do you recommend me? Should I use Google Fusion Tables or is there no alternative to storing the data redundant? Excel would be no option for me any more :8

Comment: I'd see if [Openoffice](http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOoAuthors_User_Manual/Getting_Started/Defining_relationships) or [LibreOffice](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Query_Design) would work for you.

Comment: desktop programs are to inflexible for me :) I will try google fusion tables